# How to get rid of scientific notation on bar labels in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, visualization

How could I format the bar labels to remove the scientific notation?

```
highest_enrollment = course_data.groupby(
    "course_organization")["course_students_enrolled"].sum().nlargest(10)

ax = sns.barplot(x=highest_enrollment.index, 
                 y=highest_enrollment.values, 
                 ci=None, 
                 palette="ch: s=.5, r=-.5")

ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis="y")

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0])

plt.show()
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: Did you try using the `fmt` parameter? See the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As already suggested by BigBen in the comment, you can pass `fmt` parameter to [**`matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label`**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar_label); you can use `%d` for integers:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

highest_enrollment = pd.DataFrame({'class': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'values': [30000000, 20000000, 10000000]})

ax = sns.barplot(data = highest_enrollment, x = 'class', y = 'values', palette="ch: s=.5, r=-.5")

ax.ticklabel_format(style='plain', axis="y")

plt.xticks(rotation=90)

ax.bar_label(ax.containers[0], fmt = '%d')

plt.show()
```

[image]